# dotnet core error starting application with supervisor

Tags: dotnet, supervisor

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask, but here it is:
I created an ASP.NET Core web application, and copied all the files on my Ubuntu 14.04 server. I can compile and run without a problem, but now I want this application/web site to run permanently.

I followed all the steps described here https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/linuxproduction.html, installed nginx as reverse proxy to run with apache, and all of this run perfectly well.

BUT, trying to use supervisor and start the app from it, I systematically get an error `/usr/bin/dotnet cannot execute binary file`. But, if I move to be in the directory where the application is published, and type `dotnet appname.dll` it does start without a glitch.

I am not sure where to look to get this to work with supervisor.
Thanks for your help (and if this question should be somewhere else, let me know)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your configuration file:

Change the command argumento to:

> command=/bin/bash -c "dotnet /home/username/path/application/website.dll"

Add the directory parameter to use a working folder

> directory=/home/username/path/application

Its work

Comment: It dioes work very well, indeed. Thanks, Ernesto.